# MS Access & php

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

What is the correct condition for the if statement in the code below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
 echo $sql;
 $results = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
                 if ($results){
              echo "Query Executed";
                }else {
              echo "Query failed " .odbc_error();
            }
```

or should it be

```
if ($results > 0){
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to test `odbc_exec()` for success or failure is:

```
if ($result !== false) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php) says:

> Returns an ODBC result identifier if the SQL command was executed successfully, or FALSE on error.

If a function returns a boolean (`FALSE`) or non-boolean values, be sure to use the identity comparison operator.
While `if ($result)` may work in this case (it depends on possible ODBC result identifiers), it will not work in other cases.

For example, `strpos()` returns `FALSE` if the substring is not found and the position of the substring otherwise - that means `0` is a positive result.
`if ($result)` would be wrong in this case while `if ($result !== FALSE)` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

> Returns an ODBC result identifier if the SQL command was executed
>   successfully, or FALSE on error.

So checking for a $result is OK:

```
<?php
...
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
   // OK
} else {
   // Failure
}
```